# Which original language would cause "your" to be translated to "their" in English?

Tags: translation, machine-translation

We get a significant number of emails from people who seemingly use "their" in place of "your", which leads us to believe that the mails are machine translated.

Does anyone know which language would cause this?

Here is an example:

> I understand that I am part of Group A but I have not had more Hits available for my Mturk account I feel disgusted the truth is that I like to do their job I hope and you can help me to access this job
>
> I would like to know what was the reason that they blocked me if I did not have any rechasado I would like to keep doing their hit I love those polls I like it a lot
>
> sorry for the inconvenience caused in the hit, I will be more careful therefore I want to give me another opportunity to make their hit
>
> I would like to participate in your lot, but unfortunately I have it blocked. I really enjoy doing their job and there are few like this one in Mturk, I would like to participate again thanks

Comment: More information, please; perhaps an example or three would be useful.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I still feel like I'm missing some context here. Perhaps the poster is using 'their' to refer to another group that is not 'Group A'?

Comment: No, group a is just a way for us to keep track of suspicious accounts. "Their" definitely refers to us.

Comment: *group a is just a way for us to keep track of suspicious accounts* → Does the poster know that?

Comment: I added a few more examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see now… *what was the reason that they blocked me if I did not have any rechasado* would seem to come from (Latin American) Spanish (*rechasado* not being translated because it should be written with *z* instead of *s*; Latin Americans get this wrong because *z* and *s* both sound like /s/, unlike in Peninsular Spanish, where *z* sounds like /θ/).

The original expression would be something like *qué fue la razón que me bloquearon*; here, *me bloquearon* can either mean *ellos me bloquearon* = they blocked me, or *ustedes me bloquearon* = you (pl.) blocked me; apparently the translator used picked the former meaning, even if the latter would be more appropriate here.

With regard to *their job* instead of *your job*, the cause is the same: just as *ellos* and *ustedes* use the same 3rd person plural verb forms, they command the same 3rd person possessive pronouns. Therefore *su trabajo* = their work, or your (pl.) work.